# Add new subclass to CharField

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add extra subclass to my CharField.

It would look like:

```
first_row = models.CharField('General', extra_subclass="data", help_text='q122', max_length=30, blank=True, null=False)
```

The code I tried and failed:

```
class extra_subclass(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs['extra_subclass']
        super(extra_subclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Second try:

```
class extra_subclass(models.CharField):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.kwargs['extra_subclass']= ' '
            super(extra_subclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class User1(models.Model):
first_row = extra_subclass('General', extra_subclass='hi', help_text='q122', max_length=30, blank=True, null=False)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'extra_subclass' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

Comment: This is not how you work with a subclass. Normally you subclass the field, so `class MySubCharField(models.CharField): ...`, and then you use it like `first_row = MySubCharField(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I edited and added my second try to my question. This was what I understood from your comment. Could you please clarify it for me with complete code for solution? P.S. I am still new in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your new field to fill in default values if none were given. `kwargs` is a `dict` where keys and values can be added or removed before passing it to `CharField.__init__()` (called as `super().__init__()` in this case). I used the method [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) in this example.

Maybe like this:

```
class ExtraCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # remove from kwargs, because 'super().__init__()'
        # will not accept that argument
        extra_arg = kwargs.pop('extra_arg', None)

        # set some default values if they where not provided
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 30)
        kwargs.setdefault('null', False)
        kwargs.setdefault('blank', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('verbose_name', 'General')
        kwargs.setdefault('help_text', 'q122')

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # add as an instance attribute after 'super().__init__()'
        self.extra_arg = extra_arg
```

And then use that to add a field to your model:

```
class User1(models.Model):
    first_row = ExtraCharField(extra_arg='something else')
    second_row = ExtraCharField(max_length=40)
    third_row = ExtraCharField(verbose_name='something')
    fourth_row = ExtraCharField(max_length=10, extra_arg=1234)
```

Comment: What about extra_subclass argument? You can see I mentioned it in my code. I am looking for adding extra_subclass argument into my field. Everything would be the same as CharField but with extra_subclass "add-on".